# Is there a way to print all the attributes of a composite data type in current class

Tags: c++, class, templates

Here I have a stack class in template;

```
template <class T, int s>
class stack
{
private:
  int size;  //size of stack
  T array[s]; // use array to implement stack, s is an initial argument
}
```

and a class type Book;

```
class Book
{
public:
  string title;
  int year;
}
```

I can declare a `stack<Book, 10> bs;` in main
Is there a way to print all `"title, year"` by using a function in `stack`? And remember that this is a template, it should be universal for some other classes like

```
class movie  
{
public:
  string title;
  int year;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want reflection, which C++ does not have. Your `stack` class has no function to provide what you want. You need to write one yourself.

Comment: Require each type stored in the stack has an associated stream out operator overload then iterate over each element and send them to a stream.

Comment: While this is not provided, having a base class Printable with a constructor (or advanced: type) taking all the fields in a template parameter pack can do miracles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `templating` provides compile time polymorphism which means your supposed `printAll` function will work with any type that defines the right functions, ie you could do this:

```
void printAll() {
    for (auto it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); ++array)
        cout << it->title << ", " << it->year << "\n";
}
```

But this tightly couples your class members to the stack class. You can make it more abstract by providing a general print function:

```
Book::print() {
    cout << "The book " << title << " is from " <<  year << "\n"
}
```

Then use this function in stack:

```
void printAll() {
    for (auto it = array.begin(); it != array.end(); ++array)
       it->print();
}
```

Now any type that supports a print function can be used. From here you can get continually more advanced, eg. you can overload the stream operator to do this:

```
cout << (*it);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rather expose access to `T` with e.g. an iterator, and provide a `print()` function with your `movie` class.

Tightly coupling containers to their contained items is usually a bad idea.

---

By means of standard containers I would use something like this

```
 template <typename Container>
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Container c) {
    for(auto x : c) {
       os << x << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
 }
```

and an override for class `Book`:

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Book& book) {
      os << book.title << " " << book.year;
      return os;
 }
```